# Cannot import VertexAIEmbeddings

Tags: python, langchain, openaiembeddings

I receive an error while importing VertexAIEmbeddings from langchain library:

```
  File "/app/functions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from langchain.embeddings import VertexAIEmbeddings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/embeddings/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/embeddings/openai.py", line 1, in <module>
    from langchain_community.embeddings.openai import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_is_openai_v1' from 'langchain_community.embeddings.openai'
```

The error is not directly caused by my package, but by package within mine.

The error appeared while updating my app, before it was working fine, so I guess this might be due to some package update.

My full packages list:

```
uvicorn==0.24.0
fastapi==0.95.2
langchain==0.0.350
langserve==0.0.36
sse_starlette==1.8.2
vertexai==0.0.1
google-cloud-aiplatform==1.37.0
google-cloud-storage==2.13.0
chromadb==0.4.18
langchainhub==0.1.14
unstructured[all-docs]
```